# Is thread-safe to use the 'yield' operator inside an extension method'?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, yield

Would be thread-safe to use the yield operator inside an extension method?

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<CartItem> GetItems( this Cart cart )
{
        {
            while( cart.hasNext() )
                yield return cart.GetNextItem( );
        }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the return value must be an IEnumerable, as otherwise the yield return syntax will not build.

Comment: Have I thanked you before? hehehe : P +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but yield return essentially causes the function to generate a state machine wrapper class and returns an instance of the class.  Each yield return is a return from the state machine.  The individual instance returned by a call to your method would not be thread-safe (you can't iterate on it simultaneously from multiple threads), but multiple calls would generate separate instances.  Those separate instances could be used by multiple threads and the thread-safety in that case is determined by the thread-safety of the classes used by the enumerator (`cart`'s methods, in your case.)

Comment: Thanks you Dan. you have answered my question +1

Anyway let me use a simpler example to clarify my point for further readers ; )

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer accordingly to the new example, Dan.